# not to let save on a form based on two javascript connected field

Tags: javascript

im so new on Javascripts so i wanna ask you a question.
I have two field in my entity and these are connected with javascript.

Let me explain;

Both fields has a dropdown lists and when user choose ''X'' from field A, field B is unlocked so the user can select values from dropdown list. The user can select any values that he/she wants from field B. i just dont want to be empty field B when ''X'' selected from field A. So i dont want to let the user save the entity before select something from field B.

I will be grateful if you give me the right code.

Thanks!

A friend of mine sent me the coding below but i could not write it properly. How can i write it ?

```
function ValidateData(ExecutionObj){
 //Place all your data validation here
 //In case data is not valid call the below method
 // The getEventArgs() method returns an object with methods to manage the Save event.
 // The preventDefault() method cancels the save operation
 ExecutionObj.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you're working with

Comment: i think proper sample is added.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your saving logic, just make sure that you check field B is not 'X'.

```
if ($('#fieldB option:selected').val() != 'X'){ //etc...
```

**Note:** This requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but you want to use that. Trust me.

Comment: Actually user can save the entity with no value in field B. When ''X'' selected from field B, i just dont wanna let the user save. User must select a value from field B when only ''X'' is selected from field A.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand what you're saying, but I've updated my answer. Obviously, you would replace `'X'` with the actual value you are checking for.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the select box contains a value. You could add a default selection option with a blank value `value=""` and then each other option would have a value. Then just check if the selected option has a valid value rather than blank. You can use a jQuery selector for this or native javascript if you prefer

`$('select[name="foo"] option:selected').val()`

Or native Javascript:

`var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
select.options[select.selectedIndex].value`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have written the code. i wanna share with you guys.

```
 function checkfield(Execution){
     var field = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("casetypecode");
     var field1 = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("prioritycode");
     var value = field.getValue();
     var value1 = field1.getValue();
     if (value == "3" && value1 == null) {
     Execution.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
 }
```

}

Thanks anyway!